# .net datatable alphanumerical

Tags: mysql, .net, sql

In the code below, "strdocument" can be numerical or alphanumerical but the if/count statment wont see any text but is fine with numbers only. The "strdocument" is declared AS string.

```
    Dim myadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM core WHERE F1 = " & strdocument, dbConn)
    Dim mytable As New DataTable("mytable")
    myadapter.Fill(mytable)
    If mytable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
```

so count will = 1 if strdocument is 77500 (cos 77500 is in the table) but will = 0 if strdocument is 77500A (which is also in the table)
the table is a mysql table set up in wamp and native type is varchar.

How can I get it to be alphanumerical not just numerical?

Thanks

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What is type of `F1 `

Comment: Int TSQL a literal is in single quote.  where F1 = '" & @stro & "'"

Comment: I'm wondering if you need quotes around it when it's a string? (i.e. `'77500A'` instead of just `77500A` ... not sure whether mysql uses `'` or `"` though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without quotes around your search criteria it will be interpreted as an int. For an alphanumeric litteral you need single quotes:

```
Dim myadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM core WHERE F1 = '" & strdocument &"'", dbConn)
```

Comment: Thank you Chris L, I had tried this before but missed out the last double quote, silly me;)